# Log4Net today's backup file does not have date in file name

Tags: date, log4net, filenames

Below mentioned `Log4Net`, having date in file name if date is <= yesterday, however files which are back up today, does not have date in file name.
Is it the specification of `Log4Net`?
Or
It is because of some setting of `Log4Net` config file?

File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><configuration>
<log4net>
<logger name="SampleLog">
  <level value="FATAL"/>
  <level value="ERROR"/>
  <level value="WARN"/>
  <level value="INFO"/>
  <level value="DEBUG"/>
  <appender-ref ref="SampleLogFile"/>
</logger>
<appender name="SampleLogFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="%property{SampleService}"/>
  <appendToFile value="true"/>
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="15"/>
  <maximumFileSize value="1KB"/>
  <rollingStyle value="Composite"/>
  <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd"/>
  <staticLogFileName value="true"/>
  <Encoding value="UTF-8"/>
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <!-- %d:DateTime, %t:Thread, %-5p:Categories, %c:LoggerName, %m:Message, %n:line separator-->
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%p %d{ISO8601} %t %m%n"/>
  </layout>
</appender>
</log4net>
</configuration>
```

File name example :

> Application_Sample.log  // Currently in progress log
>
> Application_Sample.log.1   // Today's backup
>
> Application_Sample.log20190801.2   // Yesterday's backup

Answer (score 0):

You just specify the **rollingStyle** as Composite, so RollingFileAppender will roll log files on a date period and within a date period on file size. For each day only the last 10 files of 1MB will be kept. And these rolled files will be named: log.txt.1, log.txt.2, log.txt.3, etc. Youcan find the details via https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html#RollingFileAppender